# Directed Acyclic Graph Question

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that in any directed acyclic graph (DAG) we have $2 \cdot |E| \leq |V|(|V|−1)$. Use induction on the number of vertices.

Comment: The title of this question is too broad as there are 'many' questions related to DAGs. Please make your title more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you have a single vertex? You have no arcs, and so $E = 0$ and $V(V-1) = 0$. When you have two vertices, you can have at most one arc. So $E = 1$, and $V(V-1) = 2$. Now assume true up to $V = K$. On the $K+1$ case, add a vertex and draw arcs from each vertex in the existing graph to the new vertex. You are adding $V$ arcs. So $2E_{k} \leq K(K-1)$ by the Inductive Hypothesis. And so $2E_{k} + 2K \leq K(K-1) + 2K = K(K+1)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $2(E_k + K)$ since you are adding K edges back?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the catch! I've updated the proof.